# Probability of random walk to stay at a fixed distance of origin

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have a point that starts at a position, let's say (0,0)

The point is going to take T steps of random walk. More precisely, at each step, my point is going to move by (dx, dy), with dx and dy following a normal distribution of mean 0 and scale theta.

Given T, theta, and a radius r, what is the probability that my point stays **everytime** inside the circle centered in my origin and of radius r?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean by every time?

Comment: At all steps ! It never leaves the circle during the whole random walk.